# How to use C# textbox inputs with C structs and imports

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct

I have library (`*.dll` file) written in C. I am trying to use it with a `Windows Form` application that I am building. I have redefined the struct that is needed for the import to work. How can I assign values to the variables in the struct.

```
[DllImport("hdnpic.dll")]
        public static extern int Hidden(Hid4cinp hid4cinp);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Hid4cinp
        {
            public const int maxSize = 500;
            public double alpha_c;
            public double alpha_m;
            public double alpha_y;
            public double alpha_k;
            public double freq;
            public double dsmp;
            public double cdxy;
            public double cdhi_c;
            public double cdhi_m;
            public double cdhi_y;
            public double cdhi_k;
            public double amp1;
            public double perd;
            public int funtype;
            public int smooth;
            public int inpres;
            public int width;
            public int height;


        }
```

I have written the code in C#. Can someone suggest me how to assign values to the Hid4cinp struct variables.

Comment: C is not the same as C++.  You should remove the C++ tag unless something is C++ related.

Comment: I see no "*native C code*", but just C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication73
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("hdnpic.dll")]
        public static extern int Hidden(IntPtr hid4cinp);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Hid4cinp
        {
            public const int maxSize = 500;
            public double alpha_c;
            public double alpha_m;
            public double alpha_y;
            public double alpha_k;
            public double freq;
            public double dsmp;
            public double cdxy;
            public double cdhi_c;
            public double cdhi_m;
            public double cdhi_y;
            public double cdhi_k;
            public double amp1;
            public double perd;
            public int funtype;
            public int smooth;
            public int inpres;
            public int width;
            public int height;


        }        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Hid4cinp hid4cinp = new Hid4cinp();

            hid4cinp.alpha_c = 123;

            IntPtr hid3cinpPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(hid4cinp));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(hid4cinp, hid3cinpPtr, true);

            int results = Hidden(hid3cinpPtr);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea @jdweng but its the 'hid4cinp.alpha_c = 123;' that is the struggle. How do I use an input from a win form textbox (C#) and allocate to that variable of the struct?

Comment: hid4cinp.alpha_c = double.Parse(textbox1.txt);